# FLTK Fl_Window inside another Fl_Window?

Tags: fltk

Can I insert one window inside another? It must be full feature, so that it receives mouse events, can be focused for keyboard input (or disabled to not receive), could be resized and have an ondraw. Can you give an example or describe?

Comment: Have you looked in the directory called test in the fltk distribution?  There is a file called subwindow.cxx.

Comment: I just installed fltk-dev using package manager, have no idea where are the samples or docs (though I installed fltk-docs as well)

Comment: Get 1.3.2 from http://www.fltk.org/software.php.  You don't need to build it but you can if you wish - just follow the instructions.  In the archive, there are two directories of interest: example and test.  Test contains samples of code for using/testing all the features of FLTK (TDD from 1998?)